# Using Gauss's Lemma to determine primes of a quadratic residue

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

The problem I'm attempting to solve is:

Apply Gauss's Lemma to determine the primes of which -2 is a quadratic residue. I'm completely lost.

Comment: With the reciprocity law (See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_law) it would be much easier to find the desired primes. Is there a special reason you want a proof only with Gauss's Lemma ?

Comment: Gauss's Lemma states that for $ a, 2a, 3a, ..., \frac{p-1}{2}a $

we take the modulus p, and get a set of equations:

$ a = r mod (p) $
$ 2a = r mod (p) $
$ .... $
$ \frac{p-1}{2}a = r mod (p) $